# Why doesn't my tuple return value to program main method correctly?

Tags: c#, tuples

I have a method which should return 2 variables from class method to main, however I am clearly using my tuple wrong as it when I check what the method returns it is incorrect.

```
using System;

namespace App1
{
     public class Player
    {
        public int Health = 100;
        public int Mana = 100;

static Tuple<int, int> SetAttributes(int pHealth, int pMana)
            {

            pHealth++;
            pMana++;
            Console.WriteLine("Health: " + pHealth + " Mana: " + pMana);

            return new Tuple<int, int>(pHealth, pMana);
            }//method end

static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            Player myPlayer = new Player();
            SetAttributes(myPlayer.Health, myPlayer.Mana);
            Console.WriteLine("In Main ...Health: " + myPlayer.Health + " Mana: " + myPlayer.Mana);

        }

    } //class End 
}//Namespace end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetAttributes returns the Tuple, so you only have the updated values in there.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player myPlayer = new Player();
            Tuple<int, int> newValues = SetAttributes(myPlayer.Health, myPlayer.Mana);
            myPlayer.Health = newValues.Item1;
            myPlayer.Mana = newValues.Item2;
            Console.WriteLine("In Main ...Health: " + myPlayer.Health + " Mana: " + myPlayer.Mana);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great and I see what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2):

In your `main`method, you are not reading the tuple from `SetAttributes()`

Here is an updated `main` method, for you to read the tuple values

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Player myPlayer = new Player();
            var tuple = SetAttributes(myPlayer.Health, myPlayer.Mana);
            Console.WriteLine("In Main ...Health: " + tuple.Item1 + " Mana: " + tuple.Item1);
        }
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netframework-4.8) is MSDN docs for tuple.

Answer (score 1):

`SetAttributes` doesn't take its arguments by reference, and you're ignoring the return value in your main method. So you're immediately discarding the incremented value.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add,
Instead of using Item1 and Item2 or other Items, you can use specific names in the Main method.

```
(int health, int mana) = SetAttributes(myPlayer.Health, myPlayer.Mana);
// Use health and mana like you normally would.
```

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't work, because health and mana are value type.

```
SetAttributes(myPlayer.Health, myPlayer.Mana);
```

This will work, because you get return value.

```
Tuple<int, int> ret = SetAttributes(myPlayer.Health, myPlayer.Mana);
myPlayer.Health = ret.Item1;
myPlayer.Mana = ret.Item2;
```